# Why does X equal to max length on each iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, tile

I've been trying to generate a two dimensional array of objects. Each object contains it's own internal position in the array in two variables called X and Y. When I instantiate the object, I can see through console logging that it's being instantiated with the proper X and Y values, this can also be validated through the fact that position in the array corresponds perfectly to those values.

However, when I log the final array after iterating through and saving each position in the array two an instance of the object, they have identical X coordinates, yet the Y coordinates are perfect.

```js
let coordinates = Array(30).fill(Array(40)) // just creates an empty two dimensional array.

class Tile {
 constructor(x,y){
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 }
}

for (let x = 0; x < coordinates.length; x++) {
 for (let y = 0; y < coordinates[x].length; y++) {
  console.log({x,y}) // logs {x: 0, y: 0} -> {x: 29, y:39}
  coordinates[x][y] = new Tile(x,y)
 }
}
console.log(coordinates) // logs two dimensional array with {x: 29, y:0} -> {x: 29, y:39}
```

I'm going mentally crazy trying to figure out why it does that. I've tried researching bindings, scope, objects instead of classes and I cannot find a way around it. I believe figuring this out will result in solving several of my problems, as I've run into other properties on the actual Tile class being randomly set despite not touching it at all. I am referring to creating a maze using deep traveling and recursion, and having each tile contain a property called "Visited" and setting it to true once it's been traversed once.

When doing that, I run into that my maze suddenly stops as it decides that every tile around it has been "visited" as they are all equal to true, yet I've never touched them.

Anything that you guys would have that would explain what I am running into would be helpful, it's no doubt something really simple and stupid.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your inner loop should read `y < coordinates[x].length` instead of `x < coordinates[x].length`.

Comment: `Array(30).fill(Array(40))` creates an array with `.length === 30`, where every spot in that array is a reference to the same array (the result of `Array(40)`).

Comment: You have 2 bugs like pointed out above, for the @Andreas one you could create the array like -> `Array(30).fill().map(m => Array(40))` instead to get unique arrays for each row rather than one array for each row..

Comment: #psdpainter - Right, that was just my own typo here on stack overflow. I do have it as y < ...

Comment: @Andreas
That is strange, I didn't actually know that it did it like that. The strangest thing is that since I posted this on SO, my friend tried to run the exact code and it worked just fine for him, so I started to assume that I have an outdated firefox & node.

Comment: @Keith
I used the shorthand you wrote there and it worked so far.

Comment: It can not work in the way you have shown. Not for you or your friend, regardless of FF, node, Chrome, in whatever version you use because that's just how JS works: https://jsbin.com/fovexokona/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

for (let y = 0; ***x*** < coordinates[***x***].length; y++) is your problem.
Your loop definitely cannot work if you are comparing to X for your Y loops, it won't ever get out.

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo in my question. I will edit it.